Neural network seems to always output the same value of about 30% when classifying
I am new to neural networks and I am currently writing a neural network that is supposed to tell if there is a cat on a picture. The training database is composed of 209 pictures that are 64x64 pixels and each pixel is a tuple (R, G, B). Database link. My Neural network uses one hidden layer and after a few hundred iterations it seems to always output 30% as the probability of a cat being there which just so happens to be the amount of cats in the training database. When i try to increase the amount of nodes in a hidden layer i get a zero division error. Below is my code:
import numpy as np
import h5py

def sigmoid(Z):
    """
    Argumenty:
    Z -- tablica numpy o dowolnym kształcie

    Zwraca:
    A -- wynik funkcji sigmoid(z), taki sam kształt jak Z
    cache -- zwraca również Z, przydatne podczas propagacji wstecznej
    """
    A = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Z))
    cache = Z
    return A, cache

 
def relu(Z):
    """
    Argumenty:
    Z -- Wynik warstwy liniowej, dowolny kształt

    Zwraca:
    A -- Parametr po aktywacji, ten sam kształt co Z
    cache -- słownik pythona zawierający "A"; przechowywany do efektywnego obliczania propagacji wstecznej
    """
    A = np.maximum(0, Z)
    cache = Z
    return A, cache


def relu_backward(dA, cache):
    """
    Argumenty:
    dA -- gradient po aktywacji, dowolny kształt
    cache -- 'Z', przechowywane dla efektywnego obliczania propagacji wstecznej

    Zwraca:
    dZ -- Gradient kosztu względem Z
    """
    Z = cache
    dZ = np.array(dA, copy=True)
    dZ[Z <= 0] = 0
    return dZ


def sigmoid_backward(dA, cache):
    """
    Argumenty:
    dA -- gradient po aktywacji, dowolny kształt
    cache -- 'Z', przechowywane dla efektywnego obliczania propagacji wstecznej

    Zwraca:
    dZ -- Gradient kosztu względem Z
    """
    Z = cache
    s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Z))
    dZ = dA * s * (1 - s)
    return dZ


def load_data():
    """
    Zwraca:
    train_set_x_orig -- tablica numpy z cechami zestawu treningowego
    train_set_y_orig -- tablica numpy z etykietami zestawu treningowego
    test_set_x_orig -- tablica numpy z cechami zestawu testowego
    test_set_y_orig -- tablica numpy z etykietami zestawu testowego
    classes -- tablica numpy z listą klas
    """
    # Implement the loading of data here
    train_dataset = h5py.File('train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
    train_set_x_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_x"][:])
    train_set_x_orig = train_set_x_orig.reshape((train_set_x_orig.shape[0], -1)).T
    train_set_y_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_y"][:])
    test_dataset = h5py.File('test_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
    test_set_x_orig = np.array(test_dataset["test_set_x"][:])
    test_set_x_orig = test_set_x_orig.reshape((test_set_x_orig.shape[0], -1)).T
    test_set_y_orig = np.array(test_dataset["test_set_y"][:])
    classes = np.array(test_dataset["list_classes"][:])
    return train_set_x_orig, train_set_y_orig, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y_orig, classes


def initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y):
    """
    Argumenty:
    n_x -- rozmiar warstwy wejściowej
    n_h -- rozmiar warstwy ukrytej
    n_y -- rozmiar warstwy wyjściowej

    Zwraca:
    parameters -- słownik Pythona zawierający parametry:
                  W1 -- macierz wag o kształcie (n_h, n_x)
                  b1 -- wektor bias o kształcie (n_h, 1)
                  W2 -- macierz wag o kształcie (n_y, n_h)
                  b2 -- wektor bias o kształcie (n_y, 1)
    """
    np.random.seed(1)
    W1 = np.random.randn(n_h, n_x) * 0.01
    b1 = np.zeros((n_h, 1))
    W2 = np.random.randn(n_y, n_h) * 0.01
    b2 = np.zeros((n_y, 1))
    parameters = {"W1": W1, "b1": b1, "W2": W2, "b2": b2}
    return parameters


def linear_forward(A, W, b):
    """
    Argumenty:
    A -- aktywacje z poprzedniej warstwy (lub dane wejściowe): (rozmiar poprzedniej warstwy, liczba przykładów)
    W -- macierz wag: tablica numpy o kształcie (rozmiar bieżącej warstwy, rozmiar poprzedniej warstwy)
    b -- wektor bias, tablica numpy o kształcie (rozmiar bieżącej warstwy, 1)

    Zwraca:
    Z -- wejście funkcji aktywacji, nazywane również parametrem przed aktywacją
    cache -- słownik python zawierający "A", "W" i "b"; przechowywany do efektywnego obliczania propagacji wstecznej
    """
    Z = np.dot(W, A) + b
    cache = (A, W, b)
    return Z, cache


def linear_activation_forward(A_prev, W, b, activation):
    """
    Argumenty:
    A_prev -- aktywacje z poprzedniej warstwy (lub dane wejściowe): (rozmiar poprzedniej warstwy, liczba przykładów)
    W -- macierz wag: tablica numpy o kształcie (rozmiar bieżącej warstwy, rozmiar poprzedniej warstwy)
    b -- wektor bias, tablica numpy o kształcie (rozmiar bieżącej warstwy, 1)
    activation -- funkcja aktywacji używana w tej warstwie, przechowywana jako tekst: "sigmoid" lub "relu"

    Zwraca:
    A -- wynik funkcji aktywacji, nazywany również wartością po aktywacji
    cache -- słownik python zawierający "linear_cache" i "activation_cache";
             przechowywany do efektywnego obliczania propagacji wstecznej
    """
    Z, linear_cache = linear_forward(A_prev, W, b)
    if activation == "sigmoid":
        A, activation_cache = sigmoid(Z)
    elif activation == "relu":
        A, activation_cache = relu(Z)
    cache = (linear_cache, activation_cache)
    return np.squeeze(A), cache


def compute_cost(AL, Y):
    """
    Argumenty:
    AL -- wektor prawdopodobieństwa odpowiadający twoim przewidywaniom etykiet, kształt (1, liczba przykładów)
    Y -- prawdziwy wektor etykiet (na przykład zawierający 0, jeśli nie-kot, 1, jeśli kot), kształt (1, liczba przykładów)

    Zwraca:
    cost -- koszt entropii krzyżowej
    """

    m = Y.shape[0]
    cost = -1 / m * np.sum(Y * np.log(AL) + (1 - Y) * np.log(1 - AL))
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    return cost
    # cost = 0
    # for val in AL:
    #     for val2 in Y:
    #         cost += (val-val2)**2
    # return cost


def linear_backward(dZ, cache):
    """
    Argumenty:
    dZ -- Gradient kosztu względem liniowego wyjścia (bieżącej warstwy l)
    cache -- krotka wartości (A_prev, W, b) pochodząca z propagacji wprzód w bieżącej warstwie

    Zwraca:
    dA_prev -- Gradient kosztu względem aktywacji (poprzedniej warstwy l-1), taki sam kształt jak A_prev
    dW -- Gradient kosztu względem W (bieżącej warstwy l), taki sam kształt jak W
    db -- Gradient kosztu względem b (bieżącej warstwy l), taki sam kształt jak b
    """
    A_prev, W, b = cache
    m = A_prev.shape[1]
    dW = np.dot(dZ, A_prev.T) / m
    db = np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m
    dA_prev = np.dot(W.T, dZ)
    return dA_prev, dW, db


def linear_activation_backward(dA, cache, activation):
    """
    Argumenty:
    dA -- gradient po aktywacji dla bieżącej warstwy l
    cache -- krotka wartości (linear_cache, activation_cache) przechowywana dla efektywnego obliczania propagacji wstecznej
    activation -- funkcja aktywacji używana w tej warstwie, "sigmoid" lub "relu"

    Zwraca:
    dA_prev -- Gradient kosztu względem aktywacji (poprzedniej warstwy l-1), taki sam kształt jak A_prev
    dW -- Gradient kosztu względem W (bieżącej warstwy l), taki sam kształt jak W
    db -- Gradient kosztu względem b (bieżącej warstwy l), taki sam kształt jak b
    """
    linear_cache, activation_cache = cache
    if activation == "sigmoid":
        dZ = sigmoid_backward(dA, activation_cache)
    elif activation == "relu":
        dZ = relu_backward(dA, activation_cache)
    dA_prev, dW, db = linear_backward(dZ, linear_cache)
    return dA_prev, dW, db


def update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate):
    """
    Argumenty:
    parameters -- słownik Pythona zawierający twoje parametry
    grads -- słownik Pythona zawierający twoje gradienty, wynik L_model_backward
    learning_rate -- współczynnik uczenia się

    Zwraca:
    parameters -- słownik Pythona zawierający zaktualizowane parametry
                  parameters["W" + str(l)] = ...
                  parameters["b" + str(l)] = ...
    """
    L = len(parameters) // 2
    for l in range(1, L + 1):
        parameters["W" + str(l)] -= learning_rate * grads["dW" + str(l)]
        parameters["b" + str(l)] -= learning_rate * grads["db" + str(l)]
    return parameters


And below my main:
import numpy as np
from utilis_chat import initialize_parameters, linear_activation_forward, compute_cost, linear_activation_backward, update_parameters, load_data

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def two_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate=0.01, num_iterations=1000):
    """
    Implementacja dwuwarstwej sieci neuronowej:
    
    Argumenty:
    X -- dane wejściowe, kształt 
    Y -- wektor prawdziwych etykiet ( 1 - 'kot', 0 - 'nie-kot'),
    layers_dims -- wymiary warstw
    num_iterations -- liczba iteracji 
    learning_rate -- współczynnik uczenia się 
    
    Zwraca:
    parameters -- słownik zawierający W1, W2, b1, b2
    """
    
    np.random.seed(1)
    # grads = {}
    costs = []  # do śledzenia kosztu
    # m = X.shape[1]  # liczba przykładów
    (n_x, n_h, n_y) = layers_dims
    
    # Inicjalizacja słownika parametrów
    parameters = initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y)
    
    # Pętla (gradient prosty)
    for i in range(num_iterations):

        # Propagacja wprzód:
        A1, cache1 = linear_activation_forward(X, parameters["W1"], parameters["b1"], activation="relu")
        A2, cache2 = linear_activation_forward(A1, parameters["W2"], parameters["b2"], activation="sigmoid")
        

        # Obliczanie kosztu
        cost = compute_cost(A2[0], Y)
        
        # Inicjalizacja propagacji wstecznej
        dA2 = - (np.divide(Y, A2) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - A2))
        
        # Propagacja wsteczna
        dA1, dW2, db2 = linear_activation_backward(dA2, cache2, activation="sigmoid")
        dA0, dW1, db1 = linear_activation_backward(dA1, cache1, activation="relu")
        
        # Aktualizacja parametrów
        grads = {"dW1": dW1, "db1": db1, "dW2": dW2, "db2": db2}
        parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
        
        # Wyświetlanie kosztów co 100 iteracji
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Cost after iteration {i}: {cost}")
        if i % 100 == 0:
            costs.append(cost)
 
    return parameters


def predict(X, parameters):
    """
    Argumenty:
    X -- dane wejściowe
    parameters -- słownik zawierający W1, W2, b1, and b2

    Zwraca:
    predictions -- wektor przewidywań naszego modelu (0: nie-kot, niebieski: kot)
    """

    A1, cache1 = linear_activation_forward(X, parameters["W1"], parameters["b1"], activation="relu")
    A2, cache2 = linear_activation_forward(A1, parameters["W2"], parameters["b2"], activation="sigmoid")

    predictions = np.round(A2)

    return predictions


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    train_set_x_orig, train_set_y_orig, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y_orig, classes = load_data()

    layers_dims = [12288, 7, 1]  #  2-warstwowa sieć neuronowa (12288 -> 100 -> 1) 12288 = 64*64*3
    parameters = two_layer_model(train_set_x_orig, train_set_y_orig, layers_dims, num_iterations=2500)

    predictions = predict(test_set_x_orig, parameters)
    print(predictions)
    print(test_set_y_orig)

I tried to fix backward propagation as i believe the problem lies there but i have been unsucesful. I suspect that the problem has something to do with the number of nodes in the hidden layer but i cannot make it to work.
